# Need to load images while scrolling listview without lag?

Tags: android, performance, listview

In my Listview, i want to load images while scrolling also as Pinterest app does.
I know there are solutions like using UIL and Volley to stop image loading on scroll to avoid lag but then how Pinterest people are handling this situation without any lag?

Anyone has any idea about this?

Comment: Being honest, dont try to rediscover the wheel. Give a try to Volley or Picasso. Pinterest people are probably using it or doing something quite similar

Comment: Picasso would be my best suggestion too. It is very easy, and image loading in a container can be obtained within one statement, and the images has a fade in effect when they are loaded which makes it more smooth

Comment: Thank you guys for response...@IbrahimYildirim but why not volley?

Answer (score 1):

load images in other thread and cancel thread if image is no longer needed. Load image with using BitmapFactory.Options and inSampleSize. This movie should be helpful http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pMRnGDR6Cu0